What would be accepted as proof of effort to look for an answer?
OK, I see that asking "what is one plus one" would deserve downvotes and comments like "what have you tried".
For mRNA vaccines and where they are going I have looked up books, searched the internet, made personal calls to the companies, but that still won't count.
So, what would be accepted as proof of effort to look for an answer?

I don’t know if this is actually fully settled here, but I went into detail on my thoughts for minimum research requirements here:
Revisiting Research, A reason to close
Generally I would like at least one link regarding the subject, strongly preferred to be from a reputable source (ideally peer reviewed).  I only come on sporadically, and no longer try to close vote frequently when I do, but if I did I would still follow this:


"I don’t know if this is actually fully settled here" ... it is fully settled here. Non of my references where accepted, and I can't give a link to a book on paper without copyright infringements. I had asked if I would get an answer if I gave references by naming page and paragraph, but there was no response to that proposition either.

I didn't see the question in reference, but I don't think a link should be required.  A book citation should be more than enough in my vote.  Presuming it's relevant.  I don't think I ever proposed that it had to be a digital source, and I would be shocked to find out that was the reason a question was closed here.  I suspect not, but again didn't see and can't comment.

@GyroGearloose "I can't give a link to a book on paper without copyright infringements" - huh? Why not?

@BryanKrause do you have a link to "The Cell"? I have not, and scanning the pages and make the contents public sure would count as copyright infringements, don't you think so?

@GyroGearloose What do you mean by asking whether I have a link to "The Cell"? What is The Cell? Why are scanning pages and making the contents public necessary to link or reference a source?

@BryanKrause this has been mentioned in the comments but then moved out of view to chat. "The Cell" I refer to is "Molecular Biology of the Cell, 3th edition", a printed book in paper. Anyway, I don't think this is of any relevance now.
